# Javascript: Using Buttons to navigate a table

Tags: javascript, dom, button

I'm having trouble figuring this out.  I've created a table, and I want to use clickable buttons (not the arrow keys) to navigate through each cell and mark that cell as yellow. The table builds and I can navigate down, but not up. Is there an easier way to traverse the table with the clickable buttons.  I have spent way too much time figuring this out to really care to admit.

edit: We're supposed to be using and navigating through the DOM to the elements.

edit 2: Fixed the issue of cell's not marking. And the buttons correctly traverse both down and up, but the UP goes into the header row which I do not wan.  Still can't figure out going right/left.   I updated the pastebin link.

edit 3: I seem to have gotten it working now.  Adding JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/rq3tjpu1/

```
 function buildTable() {

var newTable = document.createElement("table");


//Var I = Rows
//Var J = columns
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');

        if (i == 0 && j != 4){
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Header "))
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode((j+1)))
            tr.appendChild(td)

        }

        else {
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i))
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(", "))
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode((j+1)))
            tr.appendChild(td)
        }


    }

   newTable.appendChild(tr);
}

document.getElementById("tableHere").appendChild(newTable);
newTable.setAttribute("border", 3);
newTable.style.width = '50%';
return newTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign a specific value ( could be in the form of attributes) for the position of each cell? So each cell would have an X and Y value . Then you would keep a variable storing the current X and Y values. Once an arrow key has been pressed, you can use jQuery to select the cell with the required X and Y values, so for Up button that would be: (X, Y+1) , Down button (X, Y-1), Left (X-1, Y), Right (X+1, Y).

In this case it would be a good idea to use verification on the min/max  X and Y values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that is beyond the scope of the assignment.  We're supposed to be using and navigating through the DOM to the elements.

Comment: you still use this method but replace JQuery with DOM functions eg: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp. My advice would be to go with jQuery, simpler and you'll impress your tutor :)

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an example how to do that using jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/rq3tjpu1/

That's a pretty simple function

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var cell = $(".activeCell");
   var rowIndex = cell.parent().index();
   var colIndex = cell.index();
   switch ($(this).html()) {
       case "UP":
           if (rowIndex == 1)
           alert("already top");
       else 
           cell.removeClass("activeCell").parent().prev().find("td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").addClass("activeCell");
       break;
      case "DOWN":
      if (rowIndex == cell.parents("table").find("tr").length-1)
          alert("already bottom");
      else
           cell.removeClass("activeCell").parent().next().find("td:eq(" + colIndex + ")").addClass("activeCell");
       break;
       case "RIGHT":
           if (colIndex == cell.parent().find("td").length-1)
               alert("already at the right side");
           else
               cell.removeClass("activeCell").next().addClass("activeCell");
       break;
       case "LEFT":
           if (colIndex == 0)
               alert("already at the left side");
           else
               cell.removeClass("activeCell").prev().addClass("activeCell");
       break;
   }
});
```